# How to prove $0 < a_n < 1$ by induction

Tags: induction

I know $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and...

$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
0                         & \text{ if } n = 0 \\
a_{n-1}^{2} + \frac{1}{4} & \text{ if } n > 0
\end{cases}
$$

1. **Base Case:**

$$a_1 = a^2_0 + \frac{1}{4}$$

$$a_1 = 0^2 + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Thus, we have that $0 < a_1 < 1$. So our base case is ok.

2. **Inductive hypothesis**:

Assume $n$ is arbitrary. Suppose 
$$0 < a_{n} < 1$$ 
$$0 < a_{n-1}^{2} + \frac{1}{4} < 1$$ 
is true, when $n > 1$.

3. **Inductive step**:

Let's prove 
$$0 < a_{n+1} < 1$$
$$0 < a_{n}^{2} + \frac{1}{4} < 1$$

is also true when $n > 1$.

My guess is that we have to prove that $a^2_{n}$ has to be less than $\frac{3}{4}$, which otherwise would make $a_{n+1}$ equal or greater than $1$.

So we have $(a_{n-1}^{2} + \frac{1}{4})^2 < \frac{3}{4}$... I don't know if this is correct, and how to continue...

Comment: It isn't. You prove inductively that $0 \leqslant a_n \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$.

Comment: What he's trying to say is: Pretend that the problem was "Prove that $0\leq a_n \leq \frac{1}{2}$".

Comment: No. When you are inductively proving $0 \leqslant a_n \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$, in the induction step, you have the stronger assumption $0 \leqslant a_n \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$, which suffices to conclude $0 \leqslant a_{n+1} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @nbro what Daniel is telling you to do is to prove something that implies what you want to prove. Instead of proving by induction that 0< $a_n$ < 1, you prove by induction that 0 < $a_n$ < $\frac{1}{2}$. And the latter implies that 0 < $a_n$ < 1

Comment: @nbro you mean 0 < $a_n$ < $\frac{1}{2}$ ? It's simpler than what you think :) .
 You want to prove the property P : " 0 < $a_n$ < 1 ". You have several tools for this and among them, induction. But you can use something else. You can find a property A such as : A => P while being easier to prove by induction than P. So you will use induction to prove A, and then you'll know that A=> P, so you will have proven P but you'll have used induction on A :)

Comment: A:" 0 < $a_n$ < $\frac{1}{2}$ " ; P:" 0 < $a_n$ < 1 "
We agree on the fact that : A => P 
Use induction to prove A: 0 < $a_n$ < $\frac{1}{2}$
=> 0 < $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + \frac{1}{4} $ < $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$
A has been proven by induction.
Now since A => P, you have proven P to be right by proving A using induction, clearer?

Comment: @nbro you don't try to solve an inequality, you assume an inequality is true for $a_n$ and using it you want to prove that this very same inequality is also true for $a_{n+1}$

Comment: @nbro I'll add a more thorough answer, it's ok :) . Everybody has the right to be disoriented by something :), has nothing to do with stupidity
Tell me if the answer is clear enough or not, I can edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'll right it down so that it's clear to you :)

I want to prove the property P: " 0 < $a_n$ < 1 "

I look at the property A: $0 < a_n < \frac{1}{2}$

A => P, that is : If A is true then P is true

I'll prove A using induction (so technically I don't prove P by induction, but by implication).

$ a_o = 0  $ < $\frac{1}{2}$

If $ 0 < a_n < \frac{1}{2} $ , then :

$ a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + \frac{1}{4} $ > $a_n^2 $ > 0

And : $  a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + \frac{1}{4}  $ < $ (\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2} $

Hence you get : 0 < $a_{n+1}$ < $\frac{1}{2}$ :  the hypothesis holds for the rank n+1

So you have proven using induction that for every n positive integer you have :

0 < $a_n$ < $\frac{1}{2}$

But since : $\frac{1}{2}$ < 1 , you also have:

0 < $a_n$ < $\frac{1}{2}$ < 1 ie 0 < $a_n$ < 1

Comment: @nbro Of course I do, that's what the induction step is. The principle of induction is that you verify the property for the first terms , and then you suppose it is true for a arbitrary rank , usually called "n". Then, if you can prove that the hypothesis at the rank "n" implies that it is true for the rank n+1, you can conclude that it is true for every n integer. So I have to start the induction by saying "if the property 0 < $a_n$ < $\frac{1}{2}$ is true, then ..." and I finally conclude by something like " then.. 0< $a_{n+1}$ < $\frac{1}{2}$ . That's the process, you've got to grasp this

Comment: I've edited my answer, tell me if it makes more sense to you, but I can assure you that my reasoning is correct :)

Comment: @nbro, that's something that needs practice for sure :) , you'll get used to it and even have an intuitive perception throughout the learning

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $a_0 = 0$, it is easier to show the stronger inequality, $0 < a_n < 1/2$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. This conclusion immediately falls out from the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Base on the mvggz's answer, I will try to give also my complete with a lot of explanations answer. If something is wrong, please write in the comment section below ;)*

---

Let $$
a_n = \begin{cases}
0                         & \text{ if } n = 0 \\
a_{n-1}^{2} + \frac{1}{4} & \text{ if } n > 0
\end{cases}
$$

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 1$

---

1. **Basis:**

Our base case is when $n = 1$, so let's verify the following statement 
$$0 < a_1 < 1$$
We know that $a_1 = a^2_0 + \frac{1}{4}$, so we have:
$$0 < a^2_0 + \frac{1}{4} < 1$$
$a_0$ is 0, from the definition of $a_n$, so we have:
$$0 < 0^2 + \frac{1}{4} < 1$$
$$0 < \frac{1}{4} < 1$$
which is clearly true, so our base case is proved.

---

2. **Inductive step**

Let's assume that $0 < a_n < \frac{1}{2}$ (this is a stronger case, because we are assuming that $a_n < \frac{1}{2}$ instead of $<1$)

We want to prove that $0 < a_{n+1} < 1$, but if we prove $0 < a_{n+1} < \frac{1}{2}$, then we prove also the first one, because $\frac{1}{2} < 1$.

We know that:

$$a_{n+1} = a^2_n + \frac{1}{4} > a^2_n > 0$$

We know  $a^2_n > 0$, because $a_n$ is a positive number, and even though it wasn't, it would  become positive, because raised to the power of $2$, would make it positive.

Since we assume that $a_n < \frac{1}{2}$, suppose we replace $a_n$ with $\frac{1}{2}$, and we say that (note the $<$ sign):

$$a_{n+1} = a^2_n + \frac{1}{4} <  \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{4}$$
$$a_{n+1} = a^2_n + \frac{1}{4} <  \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{4}$$
which simplified becomes:
$$a_{n+1} = a^2_n + \frac{1}{4} <  \frac{1}{2}$$

and we have just proved that $a_{n + 1} < \frac{1}{2}$, so it must also be less than $1$. Note that $a_{n+1} > 0$, because $a^2_n > 0$ and also $\frac{1}{4} > 0$.