# How to systematically study the Inventor's Paradox (the more ambitious plan may have more chance of success)

Tags: logic, induction, problem-solving

I first encountered this phenomenon in undergraduate **mathematical induction**, similar to these StackExchange posts [Examples where it is easier to prove more than less](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007256/examples-where-it-is-easier-to-prove-more-than-less)
 or [Illustrative examples of a phenomenon in the logic of mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448967/illustrative-examples-of-a-phenomenon-in-the-logic-of-mathematical-induction)
. I recently encountered this phenomenon again in a logic class [image] The underlined part shows this feature.

After some google search, I found [Problems that become easier in a more general form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899109/problems-that-become-easier-in-a-more-general-form)
 that said this phenomenon was named **"The Inventor's Paradox" by George Polya**. I wonder whether this phenomenon can be **systematically studied** as a way to improve our proving techniques. I feel like it is deeply related to the study of proving techniques, which I found lacking at least in my undergraduate experience.

PS: I think many mathematical ideas that thought to be too abstract can indeed be systematically studied (like category theory?) If this is the case, I have been thinking about the role of "information/entropy" in proof. But this is probably just my imagination.